# Wordpress на Centos 7 / Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, centos, httpd

Хочу разместить 2 домена на одном сервер.

Создал пути для виртуальных хостов, тестовые страницы (index.php , index.html) по доменным именам открываются.

Apache видит и Index.php и index.html (тестовые страницы).

После установки worpress на доменах показывается заглушка Apache.

mymedhouse.ru

> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.

Comment: Просто удалите index.html

Comment: index.html - удален, он добавлялся для проверки. 
И все равно он не видит index.php , если нет файла index.html он показывает страницу Apache HTTP server

Comment: Я понял наверное из за чего этого , APache видит файл хочет запустить но у него нет доступа.

Forbidden
`You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге аппача для нужного виртуалхоста пропиши в DirectoryIndex   нужный порядок чтения файлов.
Например:

```
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html index.htm
```

Comment: Добавил строку не помогло

Comment: Эначит либо не туда добавил либо не перезапустил апач

Comment: То что ты написал верно, я не верно грешил ,у меня не index.php у меня firewall не разрешает запуск wordpresss